# What's the C++ equivalent of UINT32_MAX?

Tags: c++, types, c99

In C99, I include `stdint.h` and that gives me `UINT32_MAX` as well as `uint32_t` data type.  However, in C++ the `UINT32_MAX` gets defined out. I can define `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` before including `stdint.h`, but this does not work if someone is including my header after already including `stdint.h` themselves.

So in C++, what is the standard way of finding out the maximum value representable in a `uint32_t`?

Comment: necromantic side note: `#include <cstdint>` in C++

Comment: @AJG85 has the correct answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Not sure about `uint32_t`, but for fundamental types (`bool`, `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `float`, `double` and `long double`) you can use the `numeric_limits` templates via `#include <limits>`.

```
cout << "Minimum value for int: " << numeric_limits<int>::min() << endl;
cout << "Maximum value for int: " << numeric_limits<int>::max() << endl;
```

If `uint32_t` is a `#define` of one of the above than this code should work out of the box

```
cout << "Maximum value for uint32_t: " << numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() << endl;
```

Comment: or if `uint32_t` is a `typedef` of one of the above?

Comment: I sure hope it's a typedef.  If your tools use a `#define` for that, I question their quality.

Comment: In order to avoid numeric_limits::min(), numeric_limits::max() from being confused with std::min() and std::max() I had to enclose it in parentheses like this: (std::numeric_limits::max)();

Answer (score 32):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` defines the maximum value for type `T`.

Answer (score 25):

Well, uint32_t will always be 32 bit, and always be unsigned, so you can safely define it manually:

```
#define UINT32_MAX  (0xffffffff)
```

You can also do

```
#define UINT32_MAX  ((uint32_t)-1)
```

Comment: We don't need to resort to that when we have perfectly valid standard C++ constructs that use only 3 times as many characters.

Comment: @John: This is perfectly standard and portable as well.

Comment: And the standard libraries might not always be available - for kernel module code e.g. ...

Comment: I'd consider this only a fall back solution if neither of <limits>, <cstdint> nor <stdint.h> are available. But then, yes...

Comment: @BenVoigt I think John was being sarcastic...

Comment: @71GA: Yes, but also making a claim that C++ required you to do it a longer way to be portable / standard-compliant.  Which isn't true.  The C++ constructs he speak of allow you to use the limits in template code with type parameters, which C++ macros can never do.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment so here is my input on Glen vs Lior Kogan's answer.

If you are using static variables you will run into the problem that if you assign a constant value inside a class to numeric_limits::max() that value will be in fact set to zero because of the order of initialization (see this post [zero initialization and static initialization of local scope static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801075/zero-initialization-and-static-initialization-of-local-scope-static-variable))

So in that case it will only work by using Lior Kogan's answer.

```
// This looks cleaner, less error prone and easier to read than the other suggested by Lior Kogan
#define UINT32_MAX  ((uint32_t)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to eliminate the `#include` order problems by changing your build process to define the `__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS` symbol on the compiler command line instead:

```
cxx -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS ...
```

Of course, you would still have trouble if a header `#undef`s this symbol.

Also, the authors of the standard library implementation that you are using might not have intended for users to set that particular symbol; there might be a compiler flag or a different symbol that users are intended to use to enable C99 types in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value for any unsigned integer type T is `T(~T(0))`.