# Compute expression

Tags: c++, expression

I have:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    static int i, arr[10];
    cout<<(i==0) && (arr[i]<0);
}
```

Which means that both `i` and all of the elements of`t` are automatically initialized with `0`. Why does this expression `(i==0) && (t[i]<0)` returns true? Even this returns true:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    static int i;
    cout<<(i==0) && (i==1);
}
```

I got confused when I red this question which supposedly has the correct answer a:

1. Given the declarations:

static int i, t[10];

and assuming that neither i nor t are explicitly initialized, the value of the expression
`(i==0) && (t[i]<0)`

(a) is 1

(b) is 0

(c) depends on the context

Comment: Post a code sample showing the "problem".

Comment: `Even this returns true:` - use brackets!

Comment: Try `cout<< (i==0 && i==1);`

Comment: I edited the question so you can understand why I did not used `cout<< (i==0 && i==1);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is with operator precedence. The `&&` operator is evaluated after `<<`. Thus your print expression becomes: `(cout<<(i==0)) && (i==1);`. Correct the precedence and it prints 0 as expected: `cout<<((i==0) && (i==1));`

Comment: If in doubt: More parenthesis!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I know I should surround the whole expression with parenthesis to be sure. I edited the question to explain why I tried that way.

Comment: The C++ standard required that [both file-scoped and local static variables are zero-initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17803616/2101267). If they gave the answer of (a) as you said, they are wrong.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but trying `cout<<(i==0) && (i==1);` got me confused.