# Why isn't my array default initialization 0?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this very large array, called grid. When I declare the array as below, every value in the array should be set to 0 according to the array constructor for integers

```
int testGrid[226][118];
```

However when I iterate through the entire array, I seem to get 0s for the majority of the array, however towards the lower part of the array I get arbitrary trash. The solution it is seems is to iterate over the array and manually set each value to 0. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please make the title and body of the post compatible. You are asking two different questions.

Comment: How so? The question is why my array is not initializing all values to 0

Comment: Really? So what is "Is there a better way to do this?"

Comment: There's no such thing as an "array constructor for integers".

Comment: When you do this, this array only point to an memory, but the value, at that time, in the memory won't be changed. That's why you got those trash value.

Comment: By defaults, variables and memory allocation in C/C++ variables are not zero-initialized by default.  (Exception: global and static variables).

Comment: @RogerDwan "When you do this, this array only point to an memory". Arrays aren't pointers. People on this site need to stop telling beginners arrays are pointers.

Comment: `memset(testGrid, '\0', sizeof(testGrid));`

Comment: @Simple a pity they removed the feature where you could downvote comments

Comment: @selbie: *"variables are not zero-initialized by default"* that depends on context: if they're static or namespace scoped they are, and if there're members of a class that's initialised a la `new X();` they effectively are too due to the initiial zero-initialisation of `X`'s memory.

Comment: @M.M.: and there are situations in which value initialisation ends up doing zero initialisation (see 8.5/8).  Separately, thread local variables are another exception to selbie's comment).

Comment: @M.M.: sure... so you're saying "zero-initialisation of X's memory" sounded less like "zero initialisatoin" and more like "memory zeroing"?  Ok - good to have it clarified.

Comment: @TonyD In the [C++ standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801075/zero-initialization-and-static-initialization-of-local-scope-static-variable), the term "zero-initialization" means the all-bits-zeroing of static objects - this happens early on in program startup, before any constructors are run. Confusingly, we casually use the term to describe value-initialization. (as I did in my previous comment...)  I thought at first you were disambiguating by adding "of X's memory", but I see now that you meant value-initialization in both cases in your original comment

Comment: @M.M. there's nothing casual about this - zero initialisation is explicitly mentioned in the Standard as behaviour after startup when "there are fewer initializers than there are array elements" 8.5.2/3, and as an conditional step in value initialisation 8.5/8; I did not mean "value initialisation" in my original comment - I meant to refer only to those times when value initialisation involves a zero initialisation step.  Anyway, this isn't helping the OP....

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
int testGrid[226][118] = {};
```

which will initialize your entries to 0.

---

Please see this C [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c), which may come in handy for C++ too.

By the way, since this is C++, consider using an [std::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/), or an [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: But wouldn't that only initialize only the first value of the array?

Comment: The first value will bet set to `0`, the rest will be set to `0`. If you'd do `.. = {1}` the first element would be set to `1`, the rest would be set to `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much @juanchopanza, I updated my answer, you were right!

Comment: This is what I was thinking @juanchopanza, I will update.

Comment: It's not a better version. The version with `{}` cannot be used in C++ prior to C++11.

Comment: Are you sure @LeśnyRumcajs? I just compiled it with `g++ -Wall main.cpp` and it was fine.

Comment: @M.M No it had not. Please verify your theorem as I did. Though probably I was wrong about C++03 - `{}` does not work under C++98.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs I checked. `= {}` actually does initialize an array of ints to all `0` in C++98. (See 8.5.1/8 "An empty initializer-list can be used to initialize any aggregate", 8.5.1/7 "If there are fewer initializers in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be default-initialized", and 8.5/5 (too big to quote fully in comment) says that *default-initialized* for non-class types means zero-initialization.  (Note: This terminology changed in C++03, but not the effect)

Comment: @M.M Well then, my bad. Though on some compilers such initialization does not work (e.g. Borland C++ Builder 5). Error `expression expected`.

Comment: bcc32 is famous for terrible standards compliance. Luckily the 2015 release of the product finally ditches the old bcc32 and uses clang front end.